# SSRS Subtotal Sort Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS, how could I get the "Total Auto" subtotal to display directly under ROW #2 "BI"?

```
Coverage       Premium
----------    ------------    
No Fault       500,000           
BI             250,000
COMP           250,000
COLL           100,000
Total Auto     750,000
Total Phys     350,000
Grand Total  1,100,000
```

Comment: Could you add more detail about your Row Groups.

Comment: You can either use Row Groups, or select it that way in your SQL.

Comment: I would modify your query to add a (calculated) "ord" column.  Please show the query so I can give an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by an Aggregate (your **SUM** of `Premium`) in the Sort of the **row grouping** but not on a table itself.

[image]

You would want to set the Order to **Z to A**.

Comment: I thought you wanted to sort by value (which you can only do it on the Group) but now that I look at it again, there isn't a discernible pattern to how you want it to sort.

Comment: The way I'm reading the question, "No Fault" and "BI" rollup under `Auto`, and COMP and COLL rollup under `Phys`.   And he wants the sub-totals under their respective rollup groups.